# UiButton constraints get blown up when running app

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

Currently I am new to programming and swift and working on a project as part of my class. In my app so far when I run it, the constraints from both choice1Button & choice2Button go way off and as you can see in the picture completely get blown up. They are suppose to be small down in the bottom of the screen. This project already came with the Main.Storyboard completed and I have not touched the constraints of it. Looking into it, there is both height constraints of 100 set for both choice 1 and choice 2 .

Any help would be greatly appreciated. [This is how it's supposed to look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWGQv.png)

[Here is the constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKj3Y.png)
[Here is the Main.Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md1cu.png)

[this is how it looks when I run the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Ptw.jpg)

Comment: The provided source code is completely unrelated to auto layout constraints. Please show how the constraints are set up, instead it's impossible to guess what's the cause of the problem

Comment: A screenshot of your storyboard/xib that show the constraints of the two buttons would be the only way anyone could help you. But, in general, you would need to set up the constraints in such way that the purple button is anchored: left, bottom, right, height, and the red button: left, bottom to the top of the purple button, right, height

Comment: Sorry about that, I attached new screenshots which hopefully will help give more information. Thank you though, I think the constraints are were not set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lays in the following missing constraints that @Slavenko Miljic mentioned. The following image is an example of your project with the missing constraints.

[Your missing constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFP7d.png)